# Using Azure Storage Client Library for C++ (3.0.0) from Android NDK

Tags: c++, rest, azure, android-ndk, azure-blob-storage

We need to upload/download blobs from our c++ code in our android code. Cpp rest SDK works on Android NDK, so I can use it to call Azure storage rest API.

Azure Storage Client library is built on top of cpp rest sdk, so I am guessing that it should work on android NDK, too. But I didn't find any supporting statement on their site. Has anyone used Azure storage client library on Android NDK, please respond to this answer and also share your experience. Is it better to go use Azure storage SDK or should I stick with cpp rest SDK?

Comment: Considering for convenient and fast usage, it's better to use Azure Storage SDK for C++ that avoid to follow the REST API references to build something manually like SAS, HttpRequest options, etc. However, indeed, there is not any information of Storage C++ SDK for supporting android. Usually, users directly use Storage SDK for Android in Java, not  in C++ if have not special needs. It sounds like you have to use C++ Storage SDK on Android for some special needs or scenes, is it? Any details?

Comment: Hey, our business logic is in C++ and we want to upload and download from C++ directly to avoid back and forth between C++ and java.

Answer (score 0):

Since storage c++ lib is built on cpprest, and since that is certified for android ndk, you can use the azure storage c++ sdk.

Comment: I tried to use it on android but couldn't resolve xml parser dependencies and didn't have more time to investigate further so gave up on that. If you have working instructions for it please share. It may be useful in future.